# how to set server Session management with volley Request?

Tags: android, android-volley, session-cookies

My web server program is written in nodejs , But it does not manage session when i send request from my android app ,I have set the header along with my request, but I'm getting the same response from the server as "**Session does not exist**" , I added Cookie token along with the request header , something is missing in my Volley request Header .The code below shows my Volley response Header ... can anybody help me to make Volley request header with the cookie token ?

```
{
 Connection=keep-alive, 
 Content-Length=216,
 Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8,
 Date=Wed,
 18 Jan 2017 06:12:11 GMT,
 ETag=W/"d8-oF3uHVo3IiU9RmPHXIfBcA",
 Server=nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu),
 set-cookie=connect.sid=s%3ACeQpRX68rrYC6bebVi5F15hEN8uUmetO.GPKqnHv9VYNH83ztga3YnicAsvZ%2FSB28xUcrRGRa2sA; Path=/,
 X-Android-Received-Millis=1484719931455,
 X-Android-Response-Source=NETWORK 200,
 X-Android-Selected-Protocol=http/1.1,
 X-Android-Sent-Millis=1484719930801,
 X-Powered-By=Express
 }
```